# Choosing main based on an argument in scala sbt (or: defining alias for runMain)

Tags: scala, sbt

I have many `main`s in a project and I can choose which one to run in sbt using

```
> runMain full.path.of.main.object.
```

Unfortunately this is too verbose. In my case it is easy to generate the path of the main object from something much shorter: a number. So I was wondering if I could define a new command in sbt such that I could use:

```
> go 2
```

and this would be the same as `runMain full.path.of.main.object2`.

How can I do this?

---

Context: I have solved several [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) problems in Scala. Each solution has a different main and so far I have been compiling and running from the command line. I am new to sbt and am trying to use it with all solutions in the same project. Thus I want to choose which code to run given just the problem number.

Answer (score 2):

you can define an sbt input task and use reflection for this http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Extending/Input-Tasks.html not trivial.